# Update spinner in view and change its selected item

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I'm having trouble with quite a simple layout in Android. Basically, I have a spinner that contains several items from a sqlite database. I also have some EditText fields that receive and display the information from the selected item. What I to do now is to implement a button that allows the user to add a new entry and change its data - all in the same view (the EditText fields are already programmated to do that). Here's my code (what I tried to do is to update the database with default data from the new item and redraw the class, but I can't get to set the spinner to the new position). Do you guys have any idea on how I can do that?

```
public class Activity_MaterialTab extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_materialtab);

//Opens database
final SQLiteDatabase Estrutura = openOrCreateDatabase("Estutura.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
final Cursor cursor = Estrutura.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MATERIAIS ORDER BY [_id] ASC", null);
final Spinner spnMaterial = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mat_spn_material);
final EditText dVol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mat_frm_densidade);
final EditText modE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mat_frm_elasticidade);
final EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mat_frm_nome);
final ImageButton addMaterial = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mat_btm_add);
final ImageButton excMaterial = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mat_btm_exc);
final Bundle sis = savedInstanceState;

//Spinner
String from[] = {"_id","nome","modE","dVol"};
int to[] = {R.id.txvid,R.id.txvnome,R.id.txvmodE,R.id.txvdVol};
SimpleCursorAdapter ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.sp_material, cursor, from, to, 0);
spnMaterial.setAdapter(ad);

try {
    spnMaterial.setSelection(sis.getInt("pos"));
} catch (Exception e) {}

//Updates Edittext fields
modE.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(2)));
dVol.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(3)));

spnMaterial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor2 = Estrutura.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MATERIAIS ORDER BY [_id] ASC", null);
        cursor2.moveToPosition(cursor.getPosition());
        nome.setText(String.valueOf(cursor2.getDouble(1)));
        modE.setText(String.valueOf(cursor2.getDouble(2)));
        dVol.setText(String.valueOf(cursor2.getDouble(3)));
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});

modE.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (modE.length() != 0) { 
        String sql = "UPDATE MATERIAIS SET modE="+modE.getText().toString()+" WHERE [_id]="+String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
        Estrutura.execSQL(sql);
        }
    }
});

dVol.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (dVol.length() != 0) { 
        String sql = "UPDATE MATERIAIS SET dVol="+dVol.getText().toString()+" WHERE [_id]="+String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
        Estrutura.execSQL(sql);
        }
    }
});

addMaterial.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO MATERIAIS(nome,modE,dVol) VALUES('Nome',0,0)";
            Estrutura.execSQL(sql);
            sis.putInt("pos", cursor.getPosition());
            onCreate(sis);
            spnMaterial.setSelection(3);
        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: I would re-structure your app so that the database logic is in a separate class, and create a data object. You can then open the database, load the data via an instance of your data object, close the database, and persist the data object. Then you can make whatever manipulations you need to the object and save it to the database again as needed.

Comment: So, I thought of doing that, but I think I'd lose some of the dynamicity of the layout. Can't I use intents to do this? Pass on the last position on the cursor and call the onCreate class again?

Comment: Why would your layout be less dynamic? The goal is to loosely couple your classes in OOP, so it's just best practices. Your code will be easier to read, follow and understand too.